# how to debug to know what caused IE8 crash?

Tags: internet-explorer

when visiting certain web pages on one of websites, IE8 Crashes before it can render anything. Works on IE7 and 9 though. Im stuck with this for a couple days.

If I removed all style sheet links in the page then it worked. so looks like probably a css issue. Anyone know how to debug that to know that caused it?

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Add the style links back in one at a time until IE starts crashing again, then start commenting out blocks of that sheet until it stops crashing. the relevant section should be in the last chunk you commented.

Comment: Can you provide a repro URL?  thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be a bug with jQuery 1.6.2. If you're using XP w/ IE8, jQuery 1.6.2 and your body tag has a CSS background, IE8 will crash. The solution (workaround) is to make sure you load jQuery first and then load your stylesheet. Or you can go back to 1.6.1 as I don't believe it has this problem.

You can find more details at:
http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9028

Comment: We had 1.6.2 on XP w/ IE8 getting random crashes.  We had a background image on the body in CSS.  The error seems to have gone away.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Turned out to be the background image! Brutal!
css is like this:

```
body{
    background: url(../images/bg2.png) 50% 0 repeat-y;
    color:#7C7C7C;
    font: normal 12px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Verdana, Arial,sans-serif !important;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

turned out IE8(not 7, not 9) does not like the background image bg2.png. 
Why the heck this is happening?

Comment: We won't be probably able to help you unless you provide sufficient information. This poor piece of code is not much informative while such CSS constructions are often used without any problem and there is nothing more to investigate. Please provide URL that reproduces the problem; this might also help the IE Team to resolve the issue if it was a browser bug.

Comment: @duri:  there is really no link to the image on the internet. it is a very simple png file with dimension (3250 * 1).

Answer (score 2):

IE8 crashes on CSS are not unusual.
Some causes:

- :hover styles on elements other than links?
- overflow:scroll?
- background image on body?

You can use the standard debugging approach which Marc B already posted in his comment (remove all, add them back one by one).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same bug with jQuery 1.6.2!

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9823

Upgraded to the latest version and fixed it. Thank you for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same problem. In my case it was because I was loading modernizr after the stylesheets, instead of before them. I switched the order and it fixed it.

I wouldn't expect IE to explode over this but then, it is IE. xD

Answer (score -1):

To troubleshoot/debug IE8 crashing, save the entire HTML source as a static page using a different browser where it does work.

Start eliminating code (mainly JavaScript) to narrow down the error and retest on IE8.